# When will my Session object die?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am an asp.net novice learning MVC 4(4.5). I run the following code to store the login user name in a session when his login information is posted

```
[Anonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    Session["Username"]=model.Username;
    ///something else
}
```

And in another file somewhere there I can use `Session["Username"]`. Ok, my question for my current confusion crops up as to when this object will be garbage-collected or destroyed.

I know in another scripting language like PHP, I have to call
`session_start()` and `session_end()` in all of the files that needs use of this similar session object data. I can't find the same things in a newly created MVC 4 project but authentication mechanism seems all done for me somewhere.

Comment: Probably when the session expires? I'm sure that is configurable, though

Comment: no telling. depends on your server load, if you're using load balancing, your set timeout... things in your control and things out of your control. Unless you use cookies.

Comment: No, this doesn't depend on server load. The Cache depends on it, the Session is guaranteed to always persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when this object will be garbage-collected or destroyed.

When the session expires. The session state is configured in your web.config using the [`<sessionState>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) node. You may take a look at the [`following overview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) about sessions. By default ASP.NET stores session data in-memory. This means that if your application is running in a web farm you will have problems because the different nodes of this webfarm might not *see* the value that was stored on some other node. If you want to use sessions in such scenario you will have to configure an out-of-process session state such as `StateServer` or `SqlServer`. Another problem with the default `InProc` session state mode is that if IIS decides to recycle your application you might loose the data that is stored inside. Yet another reason not use session at all or use an out-of-proc session storage.

So for example you could specify a timeout for your session like this:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />
```

The default value is 20 minutes. But once again it will depend on the mode you are using.

> I know in another scripting language like PHP, I have to call
>   session_start() and session_end() in all of the files that needs use
>   of this similar session object data.

No need to worry about such things in ASP.NET MVC.

---

Now all this being said, I would recommend you not using any session at all. ASP.NET already provides you with the necessary mechanism to track authenticated users. You could use [`Forms Authentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) which is designed exactly for the purpose of securely tracking authenticated users.

So start by turning off the ASP.NET session:

```
<sessionState mode="Off" />
```

and then:

```
[Anonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    // TODO: check credentials, ...

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false);
    //something else

    // finally redirect and inside the target controller action
    // you will be able to retrieve the authenticated user
    return RedirectToAction("SomeProtectedAction");
}
```

and then you could decorate protected controller actions that are accessible only by authenticated users with the `[Authorize]` attribute and inside them retrieve the currently authenticated user:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult SomeProtectedAction()
{
    string username = User.Identity.Name;
    // something else ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Global.asax

There you have events for everything ranging from application start to sessions to requests begin/end and more...

Note however that the 'end' methods are not guaranteed to be invoked. So don't count on them.

And if you decide to use sessions, don't spill it with strings like you do in your example. Make a class with proper properties for your session and a SessionManager to deal with it. It will help you a lot in the long run.